# How to break long HTML string in email body

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a long HTML string as my email body and I need to insert new line characters (`"\n"`) to split the HTML into several lines, because mail servers have problems with long lines.

How do I do it without breaking the HTML tags?

I'm not talking about adding new line-breaks (`<br>`) in the HTML, I want to insert new line characters in the string so when mail servers fetch HTML line by line it shouldn't reach the line length limit.

For example:

If I have a HTML string:

```
<head><title>Enter a title, displayed at the top of the window.</title></head><body><h1>Enter the main heading, usually the same as the title.</h1><p>Be <b>bold</b> in stating your key points. Put them in a list: </p></body>
```

I want to insert new line-breaks:

```
<head>\n<title>\nEnter a title, displayed at the top of the window.\n</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>\nEnter the main heading, usually the same as the title.\n</h1>\n<p>\nBe <b>bold</b> in stating your key points. Put them in a list: \n</p>\n</body>
```

[image: RFC line length limit]

Comment: use <br> tag in html for new line

Comment: i'm not talking about this, i want to split long html string into smaller chunks.

Comment: you want to write long string in multiple lines right?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: also added example

Comment: \n will not work inside string , where you use \n replace it with br.

Comment: i'm not talking about new lines in html result. i want to just insert new line characters in the string so that if we fetch html line by line it shouldn't reach the line length limit.

Comment: Why are you passing html in ActionMailer?  There are templates for this.  You're just supposed to pass in the variables that change.

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us you edited the question, and "edited" or "updated" tags in the text are undesirable. Simply edit the question, add the new information as if it'd always been there. Readability and comprehension are much more important than trying to maintain a sense of the edit history. We can see what changed and when if we need to.

Comment: Personally, I'd run the HTML through  "[tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/)". It's highly configurable and  can break lines where it's logically sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many HTML emails use the [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding:

```
<head><title>Enter a title, displayed at the top of the window.</title></he=
ad><body><h1>Enter the main heading, usually the same as the title.</h1><p>=
Be <b>bold</b> in stating your key points. Put them in a list: </p></body>
```

In the above encoding, a trailing `=` marks the end of a line but doesn't break it. The original string can be reassembled by joining the lines accordingly.

Fortunately, there's no need to re-invent the wheel. The excellent [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem can do that for you: (and much more, you want to check out [multi-part](https://github.com/mikel/mail#writing-and-sending-a-multipartalternative-html-and-text-email) emails)

```
require 'mail'

mail = Mail.new do
  content_type 'text/html'
  content_transfer_encoding 'quoted_printable'
  body "<head><title>Enter a title, displayed at the top of the window.</title></head><body><h1>Enter the main heading, usually the same as the title.</h1><p>Be <b>bold</b> in stating your key points. Put them in a list: </p></body>"
end

puts mail.to_s
```

Output:

```
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 16:44:11 +0200
Message-ID: <5ed7b7...>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<head><title>Enter a title, displayed at the top of the window.</title></=
head><body><h1>Enter the main heading, usually the same as the title.</h1=
><p>Be <b>bold</b> in stating your key points. Put them in a list: </p></=
body>=
```

Since you tagged your question [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), you might also want to check out [Action Mailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Comment: hi @Stefan, thanks for the answer. I'm using rails 4.1 and it seems like action mailer does not handle line length limit automatically. this is what i get from mail.to_s:

`Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`

Comment: by setting `mail.transport_encoding = "quoted-printable"` we can change the Content-Transfer-Encoding to `quoted-printable` but still if you know a better solution then please update your answer. Thanks a lot!